# SharpSSH with Persistent ShellExec connections

Tags: c#, ssh, sharpssh

I'm using SharpSSH to connect to an SSH server and I've tried using both SshShell and SshExec.
I need to be able to take a series of commands and send them to the server in order, so SshShell doesn't really do what I need since I would have to wrangle streams the whole time and it seems that it would be a bit of a kludge.  So I've tried SshExec but found one problem with it, every time I send a command it seems to be making a new connection and losing the context of the last command.  For example if I ran the following commands:

```
pwd
cd .ssh
pwd
```

I would expect it to output

```
/home/adam

/home/adam/.ssh
```

But, instead it just ouputs "/home/adam" both times, meaning that the directory change was lost in between.

Is there a way I can configure this so that it maintains a constant connection to the SSH server until I tell it to disconnect?

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
exec.RunCommand("pwd; cd Desktop; pwd")
```

I am not sure how to do advanced commands, but I tried that and it outputs:

```
/Users/MyUser
/Users/MyUser/Desktop
```

Comment: This is exactly what I had to do to get this to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To cd to a hidden directory (any directory beginning with a dot (.) character), you need to enclose the value in quotes.

According to [the documentation](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/cd.html):

> 4) If the first component of the directory operand is dot or dot-dot, proceed to step 6.
>
> 6) Set curpath to the string formed by the concatenation of the value of PWD , a slash character, and the operand.

In short, `cd '.ssh'` should do the trick.

Comment: I mistyped, and that was just a example.  The issue is still the same though... any example you want, the context does not persist.