# C#: Tamir.SharpSsh unable to change directory in unix

Tags: c#, unix, ssh, cd, sharpssh

I am currently making a File-Dialog-like form in C# that browses directories on a unix server.
I have a bit of a trouble getting the 'cd ..' command to work.

Here is an example of my code

```
    var sshExec = new SshExec("192.x.x.x", "user", "pass");
    sshExec.Connect();
    var err = string.Empty;
    var out = string.Empty;
    sshExec.RunCommand("pwd", ref out, ref err);
    Console.Writeline(out);
    sshExec.RunCommand("cd ..");
    sshExec.RunCommand("pwd", ref out, ref err);
    Console.Writeline(out);
```

I've tried other formats such as `cd ..` or $"cd .." and yet I seem to remain in the same
directory.
I guess every time I use RunCommand() sshExec creates a new transaction therefore I stay
in the same directory.

Anyone knows how can I make this work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SharpSSH with Persistent ShellExec connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141570/sharpssh-with-persistent-shellexec-connections)

Comment: Also see related posts like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280021/sshexec-of-sharpssh-disconnects-when-runcommand-method-is-used?rq=1

Comment: Woah, haven't seen that one, but my problem is almost identical. Although, none of the posts above seems to be solving my problem.

Comment: Not going to lie, the SharpSSH library isn't too solid nor updated. I would look at SSH.net on Codeplex for something that's been written for .NET instead of a Java port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sshExec.RunCommand("pwd", ref out, ref err);
sshExec.RunCommand("cd ..");
sshExec.RunCommand("pwd", ref out, ref err);
```

Each call to `RunCommand()` will create a separate channel which runs independently of the others. In the common case (making an ssh connection to a unix server), each channel will invoke a separate shell instance. A command like `cd` run in one channel won't affect subsequent commands launched in different channels.

To do what you want, you have to arrange to run the sequence of commands in the same `RunCommand` invocation. Assuming the remote server is a unix server invoking a shell like `bash`, you can use shell syntax, for example:

```
sshExec.RunCommand("pwd && cd .. && pwd", ref out, ref err);
```